# Google maps api creating heatmap based on state instead of geo coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Trying to create a heatmap by States and I'm basing my map on this sample:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/layer-heatmap

but I got a quick question, is it possible to provide google maps api with a state entry instead of coordinates? For example:

Instead of:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(37.765172, -122.417556),
new google.maps.LatLng(37.765164, -122.418075),
```

I would have something like...

```
new google.maps.state("NY"),
new google.maps.state("NJ"), etc.﻿
```

Comment: The link goes to a 404 page.

Comment: @Lee they've changed the documentation since.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to geocode the addresses first and use the return value as input to the new.google.maps.latLng method. You could use the Google Geocode service to streamline the process. The class to use is: google.maps.Geocoder().

edit: I actually dug up an old script I used a while ago. I used pygeocoder for it. See below for a subset of it

```
import sys
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
from pygeocoder import Geocoder,GeocoderError

addressList = ["553 Main St, Toronto, On", "2 Black Creek Dr, Toronto, On"]
geocodedList = []

for item in addressList:
    result = Geocoder.geocode(item)
    coordinates = str(result[0].coordinates)
    geocodedList.append(coordinates) #from here, parse out x and y
```

Comment: I've tried using python's geopy's geocoder module, but found issues, IL, USA gives no matches, but NY, USA does :'(

Comment: Thanks @dgalati, I'm guessing it wouldn't work that well if I just did: IL, USA or NJ, USA? I'll try this when I get home